# Getting the FormController of a form

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have code like this in my controller:

```
var forms = $('form'); // my selector is a bit more complex.
var form = forms[0];
```

This gives me the form. From this how do I get hold of the [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) so that I can check on properties like $pristine, $invalid, etc.?

```
var formController = // how to get this from form?
var ispristine = formController.$pristine;
```

I actually have multiple child forms and I will have to get the pristine state of them all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured that you can do this to get hold of the "FormController" properties of a form:

```
    // Get hold of the form in your DOM
    var forms = $('form');
    var form = forms[0];

    // Get hold of the form's scope object, which is injected with an object containing these properties.
    // Note that 'formName is the name of the form element in html. (<form name='formName'>....</form>
    var formScope = $(form).scope().formName;
    var ispristine = formScope.$pristine;
```

Note that this works only if the form element has a name attribute!